# CreateAPIView returns TypeError with st() function, when accessing endpoint via browser

Tags: python, django, rest, frameworks

I am writing API based on Django (2.2.2) and Django Rest Framework (3.9.4).
Goal is to create simple message system.
After creating endpoint for creating message, I get TypeError:

```
TypeError at /api/v1/message/create/
__str__ returned non-string (type Message)

The 'message_body' in the DB contains PL characteristic characters.
```

I tried both serializer.Serializer and serializer.ModelSerializer for my serializer, CreateAPIView and ListCreateAPIView for the view.
What is really interesting, endpoint for listing out the messages is working just fine.

This is nearly copy-paste code from my other endpoint (also CreateAPIView), which is working just as expected.

I also tried some encoding stuff on **str**(self), but guess not properly.

### sample.json: (fixtures to test API in the browser)

```
{
  "model": "core.message",
  "pk": 1,
  "fields": {
    "chat": 1,
    "message_body": "Wiadomość testowa 1",
    "sender": "user",
    "sent": "2019-05-05T10:20:37+01:00",
    "is_viewed": true
  }
}
```

### models.py:

```py
class Message(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing single message in DB
    """
    chat = models.ForeignKey(
        'Chat',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        unique=False
    )
    message_body = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    sender = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message_body

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message_body.decode('utf8')
```

### views.py:

```py
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from message.serializers import (
    ListMessageSerializer,
    CreateMessageSerializer
)
from core.models import Message



class CreateMessageView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Create new message view
    """
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = CreateMessageSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """
        Save data to DB, if valid
        """
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors,
                status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

### serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from core.models import Chat, Message


class CreateMessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for creating ne message
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = (
            'id',
            'chat',
            'message_body',
            'sender',
            'sent',
            'is_viewed'
        )
        read_only_field = ('id',)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        """
        Validate request data
        """

        message_body = attrs.get('message_body')
        if not message_body or message_body is None:
            msg = _('Can\'t send empty message!')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authentication')

        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Insert Message into DB
        """

        return Message.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

### url.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from message import views


app_name = 'message'
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.CreateMessageView.as_view(), name='create'),
]
```

I'd like to be able to open the view in the browser at:
api/v1/message/create/
and test creating new messages by hand :)

Comment: What version of Python and Django are you using?

Comment: Django 2.2.2, Python 3.7.3, DRF 3.9.4

Comment: So your `__unicode__` method is pointless and will never be called. But can you explain why you're calling `decode` in the `__str__` method? What makes you think the contents of the body field is bytes?

Comment: It was a long shot, a bit desperate I admin. Should the content in DB have to do something with the error?
I have just thought of something. The TypeError msg tells about **__str__()** returning type  "Message" - which is name of my Model. Does not defining  a **get()** and queryset may have sth with the matter?

Comment: But what happens without that decode?

Comment: Still same. Even if I change **__str__()** to:
```python
def __str__():
  return 'String'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the reelationship between PrimaryKeys of:
Chat - parent of Message in DB

Now everything is working :)